# How to solve difficult sentences for nlp sentiment analysis

Tags: nlp, sentence

Such as the following sentence,
"Don't pay attention to people if they say it's no good."
As humans, we understand the overall sentiment from the sentence is positive.

1. Technique of "Bag of Words" or BOW
   Then, we have the two categories of "positive" words as Polarity of 1, "negative" words of Polarity of 0.
   In this case, the word of "good" fits into category, but here it is accidentally correct.
   Thus, this technique is eliminated.
2. Still use BOW technique (sort of "Word Embedding")
   But take into consideration of its surrounding words, in this case, the "no" word preceding it, thus, it's "no good", not the adj alone "good".  However, "no good" is not what the author intended from the context of the entire sentence.

Thus, this question.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Word embeddings are one possible way to try to take into account the complexity coming from the sequence of terms in your example. Using pre-trained models on general English such as BERT should give you interesting results for your sentiment analysis problem. You can leverage on several implementation provided by [Hugging face](https://huggingface.co/) library.

Another approach, that doesn't rely on compute intensive techniques (such as word embeddings), would be to use n-gram which will capture the sequence aspect and should provide good features for sentiment estimation. You can try different depth (unigram, bigrams, trigrams...) and combine with different types of preprocesing and/or tokenizers. Scikit-learn provides a good reference implementation for n-gramss in its [CountVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) class.

Comment: if you're satisfied with the answer, don't forget to mark it ;-)

Comment: too bad, stackoverflow is crazy, it does not give me privilege to vote up for your answer.  in addition, i may have follow-up questions for you on n-gram, right now I have to put out a 'fire'.